# Error in jquery in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have problem in jquery,
When you move the code to work on the laravel, this problem appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDApG.jpg)

That's my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keCDv.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your actual code instead of pictures of your code.

Comment: A code is a text not a link, please post it on description.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asset()` helper like this :

```
    <script src="{{ asset('timber/js/jquery-1.8..3.min.js') }}"></script>
    {{-- other links with same logique --}}
```

And make sure that the `timber` directory is in public `directory`